# Reach Router not showing correct component for matched url

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

With the following I can navigate to `/shop/`, `/shop/dept1/`, `/shop/dept2/`, and see the component I expect to see.

When I try navigating to `/shop/dept1/?option=...`, I still only see the DeptOne component, not the PLP component. I'm almost positive I've done something similar to this in the past, but can't seem to replicate it this time.

```js
<Router basepath='/shop'>
    <Shop path='/' />
    <DeptOne path='/dept1/' />
    <DeptTwo path='/dept2/' />
    <PLP path='/dept1/*' />
    <PLP path='/dept2/*' />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL query parameters (the key-value pairs after the ?) are not part of the path. So for `/shop/dept1/?option=...` the path is still `/shop/dept1/`.

This means that the component for path `/shop/dept1/` must handle the query parameters. The query parameters can be accessed in the component via the `location` object, which is a prop for Router (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location).

You could for example make a wrapper component:

```js
const WrapperComponent = ({ match, location }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <DeptOne />
      {location.search == ""
        ? null
        : <PLP queryParams={location.search}>
      }   
    </>
  );
}
```

The `queryParams` prop is a string that starts with the ?. So if the path is `/shop/dept1/?option=...` queryParams will be `?option=...`.

More info [here](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/).